# Why is @font-face not able load all font weights in ttf format?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, same-origin-policy

I have a demo of my landing page working on github https://anupamkhosla.github.io/omcarreer/ In the css I have the following code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: lighter;  
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;  
}
```

The font *Open Sans* is downloaded from Google https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans The files are downloaded as ttf `truetype`.

The `h1` tag saying *"We are the most trusted brand in recruitment fraternity."* is supposed to take lighter font weight, but what is happening is that all browsers seem to disregard the first `font-face` declaration and hence do not load the lighter version of the font. If I interchange the font-face declarations' positions then again the one mentioned at last seems to be respected. You can see the font face declarations in the css file here https://anupamkhosla.github.io/omcarreer/css/main.css If you open the `Networks` tab in `inspect element` you will see only the later mentioned font is being loaded.

Why is `font-face` being overridden like this? I used to make other websites with similar font-face declarations and never had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value "lighter" can be used in a font-weight property applied to content elements, meaning lighter than the inherited value. (See [CSS Fonts Module Level 3, §3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#font-weight-prop).

But in an `@font-face` rule, "lighter" is not a valid value. (See [CSS Fonts Module Level 3, §4.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#font-prop-desc). And it wouldn't make sense: *lighter than what?*

In the `@font-face` rule, you should use `font-weight: 300`.

Comment: Fork me dead mate, what a spin out. ... And I am thinking later declarations of `@font-face` are overriding the former ones :-/. I should have gone through the `font-face` reference of `font-face` page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-weight